# Is there a proper work-around for overloading methods that need to take the same value types, or should it just be avoided?

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm programming in c# and this is more of a best practices question.

I wanted to create an overloaded method and accidentally made two methods with the same value types as arguments. I wanted to use the same method name to keep things simple when writing code later so I added another int argument as a throw-away to the overload just to separate it from the first method. This doesn't seem like a good coding practice to me, but it did work.

Example here:

```
public static void SetBalance(Customer cust, int index)
{
    cust.Balance = balanceList[index];
}

public static void SetBalance(Customer cust, int value, int notUsed)
{
    cust.Balance += value;
}
```

My question: Is there a more clever or more appropriate way to work around having the same value types as method arguments in an overload, or is simply creating a new method with a different name the best solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you need a method to simply set a property at all?  `SetBalance()` makes nothing simpler, shorter, cleaner or clearer for any actor calling `SetBalance`.

Comment: Why is a method that increments the balance being given the name **Set**Balance? In any case, this is at best just "don't do that", and at worst a primarily-opinion-based question. I think you will find that any time you run into this type of situation, there are better names you can pick for the method. So, do that.

Answer (score 2):

You would do better to name the first method something like `RefreshBalance`, since the resulting value of the customer's balance is not related to any arguments present in the method.

The second method would be better named something like `AdjustBalance` or `IncrBalance` for similar reasons. Two methods with plainly different behaviors should not have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is the naming convention. Both of these methods perform different operations so you should give them proper names SetBalance() and AddBalance() etc.

Answer (score -4):

When you overload a constructor you shouldn't have two constructors with the same argument pattern as

```
public static string myConstruct(Customer cust, int index){}
public static string myContsruct(Customer cust, int age){}
```

As an example the two constructors have the same argument pattern so you'll end up with a error when compiling. To get around this just swap the arguments around on the second constructor as

```
public static string myContruct(Customer cust, int index){}
public static string myContruct(int age, Customer cust){}
```

This will avoid any conflicts.

Comment: IMO, swapping the order makes it difficult to peruse overloads in intellisense as you type (among other things).  Look at the `Graphics.DrawString` overload for an example

Comment: Maybe you should down mark Microsoft too. Because thats where i originally got the idea from!